# Rotation interpolation knowing values at specific points

Tags: algorithms, curves, rotations, computational-mathematics, spline

Let's say we have an arc-length parametrized curve $\mathcal{C}(s)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
We want to find a frame $\mathcal{R}(s)=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{\mathbf{t}} & \hat{\mathbf{b}} & \hat{\mathbf{n}}\end{array}\right]\in SO(3)$ along $\mathcal{C}$, so that $\hat{\mathbf{t}}=\dfrac{d\mathcal{C}}{ds}$
and $\hat{\mathbf{t}}\bot\hat{\mathbf{b}}\bot\hat{\mathbf{n}}$, knowing
$\mathcal{R}_{i}(s_{i})$ at some points $1\leq i\leq m$. How can
this problem be approached in a computationally efficient manner?
Of course, one possibility is to formulate a constrained optimization
problem, minimizing for example the norm of the second derivative
of the rotation interpolator (expressed in any suitable parametrization,
for instace by means of quaternions). The problem is, the rotation
interpolator must be obtained in real time, so I would need a faster
(approximate) method. The samples $\mathcal{R}_{i}(s_{i})$ may be
far apart, so orthogonalization may not always lead to a suitable
solution.

Thanks a lot for your help!